# Web Scraping C# with (possibly) a masked IP

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've gone away and tried my hand as some Web Scraping in C#. I found a video by Blake B on Youtube which shows the process of getting Ebay listings into a list, pretty cool. I am also trying to do something similar but I'm struggling on the HTML part on what to substitute where, this is what I have so far...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace CarRegRetrieve
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetHTMLAsync();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async void GetHTMLAsync()
        {
            var url = "https://www.rapidcarcheck.co.uk/results?RegPlate=LN52dmv";
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

            var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

            var ProductsHTML = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("body")
                .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("wpb_text_column wpb_content_element", "")
                .Equals("wpb_wrapper")).ToList();

            var productLists = ProductsHTML[0].Descendants();

            Console.WriteLine(productLists);

        }

    }
```

This is the beginning of what should be a scrape to get car information by an entered registration, as you can see, the website I am using is RapidCarCheck and I have entered my registration and would like to get the engine size, top speed etc. I have had a look at the inspect element on the page, but have no idea what I am looking for.

A little side note, note sure if it's an easy fix, but the site as a Cloudfare anti-request blocker type thing, and without a proxy to hide or change my IP makes it hard to code the project as I keep needing to change my IP manually.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not super helpful, but I'd recommend looking into eBay's API. Web scraping -while possible- is generally not a great idea. Unless there's some requirement that says you need to scrape web pages, I'd avoid trying it.

Comment: Hello @Dortimer, thanks for the quick reply, I am currently studying for my A levels and my coursework is to make software for calculating finances for cars, I was hoping to add this feature of getting information from that website aforementioned to add a little 'refinement' to the project :)